# Find Missing Number in a Range- Javascript challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone help me get started on this challenge:

> Given an array of 99,999 unique numbers ranging from 1 to 100,00 in a random order, find the one number that is missing from the list.

I'm not sure how to start thinking about it.

Comment: You should re-phrase the question and also provide some attempts.

Comment: how are you filling 10000 integers in an array of 99999 withour repitition

Comment: @Ankit: I think that's a typo, I think it's 1 to 100,000 -- but of course, you can do the other, as well, they just won't be *whole* numbers.

Comment: Rory, did you mean 1 to 100,000 rather than 1 to 100,00? (That latter doesn't make sense if `,` is the thousands separator, but in some locals it's a decimal point, so...)

Comment: ("locales", I meant)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Except for the missing number, you are describing an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), which has a nifty formula to calculate its sum. So you could loop over the array, sum it, and then subtract that from the formula. The difference would be the missing element:

```
function missing(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    var expected = 100000 * (1 + 100000) / 2;
    var missing = expected - sum;
    return missing;
}
```

Comment: A bit more than just helping OP to start thinking of the problem themselves, but yes it's correct

Comment: I think you mean `arr[x]` in the loop?

Comment: Don't use `for in` to loop through arrays, or if you do, use safeguards. [Better options in this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)

Comment: @NiklasB. - yup, was missing the `/2`, edited. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just making my first steps in JS, thanks for the insight. I went back to the old fashioned `for` loop - as you mentioned, sometimes, the old ways are the best ways.

Comment: line 3: a is not defined, there must be arr

Comment: @Serg the copy-and-bug idiom :-) lost concentration there for a minute, thanks!

Comment: @Mureinik: :-) I hate to say it, but now you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). I've taken the liberty of fixing it for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it without wasting any space storing numbers,

start with [1+2+3+4+... sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Then subtract each number in the array from the sum